# Impyla connection. Cannot start SASL. No mechanism available

Tags: python, impala, sasl, impyla

I am trying to connect to impala using impyla, each time I am getting this error

```
 Could not start SASL: b'Error in sasl_client_start (-4) SASL(-4): no mechanism available: Unable to find a callback: 2'
```

I have installed:

```
impyla==0.16.2
thrift_sasl==0.4.2
thrift==0.13.0
thriftpy==0.3.9
thriftpy2==0.4.11
```

I am connecting using

```
connect = connect(host=server, port=21050, user=login, password=passwd, use_ssl=True, auth_mechanism='LDAP')
```

I used this previously on python 2.7 and it was working, now when i moved to 3.6 it stopped.

edit:
I was digging little bit more and it seems that thrift_sasl is not recognising 'LDAP' authentication

```
TTransportException                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-562dbef67d96> in <module>
      7 select_offset = 0
      8 
----> 9 connect = connect(host='azrudb7006.ra.rockwell.com', port=21050, database=db_name, user=login, password=passwd, use_ssl=True, auth_mechanism="LDAP")

~\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\impala\dbapi.py in connect(host, port, database, timeout, use_ssl, ca_cert, auth_mechanism, user, password, kerberos_service_name, use_ldap, ldap_user, ldap_password, use_kerberos, protocol, krb_host, use_http_transport, http_path)
    148                           auth_mechanism=auth_mechanism, krb_host=krb_host,
    149                           use_http_transport=use_http_transport,
--> 150                           http_path=http_path)
    151     return hs2.HiveServer2Connection(service, default_db=database)
    152 

~\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\impala\hiveserver2.py in connect(host, port, timeout, use_ssl, ca_cert, user, password, kerberos_service_name, auth_mechanism, krb_host, use_http_transport, http_path)
    823                                 auth_mechanism, user, password)
    824 
--> 825     transport.open()
    826     protocol = TBinaryProtocol(transport)
    827     if six.PY2:

~\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\thrift_sasl\__init__.py in open(self)
     94       if status not in (self.OK, self.COMPLETE):
     95         raise TTransportException(type=TTransportException.NOT_OPEN,
---> 96           message=("Bad status: %d (%s)" % (status, payload)))
     97       if status == self.COMPLETE:
     98         break

TTransportException: Bad status: 3 (b'Unsupported mechanism type ')
```

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this error. The only solution is to remove sasl and use pure-sasl.

My requirements:

```
thrift-sasl==0.4.2
pure-sasl==0.6.2
impyla==0.16.3
```

For Windows, sasl is not installed and therefore can work without problems, but on Linux machines it needs to be removed (pulled up inside thrift_sasl) otherwise, the factory for connecting via sasl does not work correctly inside the impyla library.

It also allows you to get rid of the error: TProtocolException No protocol version header

My realization:

```
from impala.dbapi import connect
from impala.hiveserver2 import HiveServer2Connection

from config import Config


def init_connection():
    auth_mechanism = 'PLAIN'

    return connect(host=Config.HIVE_HOST,
                   port=Config.HIVE_PORT,
                   user=Config.HIVE_USER,
                   auth_mechanism=auth_mechanism)


class PyHive:
    conn: HiveServer2Connection = init_connection()

    def __init__(self):
        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()

    def __enter__(self):
        return self.cursor

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self.cursor.close()
```